# RNN: What is the use of return_sequences in LSTM layer in Keras Framework

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working in RNN. I have following lines of code from some site.
If you observe second layer has no "returnSequence" parameter.

I am assuming return sequence is mandatory as it should return the sequences.
Can you please tell why this is not defined.

First layer LSTM:

```python
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 30, return_sequences = True))
```

Second layer LSTM:

```python
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 30))
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you think it 'should return the sequences'?

Comment: Thanks for replying. As in RNN at every time step the output is feeded into itself and hence I am assuming return_sequence should be true.  COuld you tell then what exactly this return_sequence does?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the `return_sequences` argument is set to `False` (default), the network will only output h<sub>n</sub>, i.e. the hidden state at the final time step. Otherwise, the network will output the full sequence of hidden states, [h<sub>1</sub>, h<sub>2</sub>, ..., h<sub>n</sub>]. The internal equations of the layer are unchanged. Refer to the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/).

Comment: Thank-you konstantinos. Got you.

Comment: What does it give setting `return_sequences` to `True` or `False` regarding practical usage?

Answer (score 0):

when the LSTM layer is followed by a Dense layer you should set return_sequence=False, otherwise when you use several LSTM layers stacked together you should set it to TRUE

```
LSTM(units, return_sequences=True...)
LSTM(units, return_sequences=True...)
LSTM(units, return_sequences=False...)
Dense(...)
```