# How to build many to one LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to predict the S&P index with multiple features. Below is the sample dataset I have which includes the close price of different indices.

I have built a many-to-many LSTM model which predicts the close price for each index. However, is it possible to use the other 5 indices to forecast only the S&P index?

Model:

```
model_lstm.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(units=50))
model_lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
model_lstm.add(Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))
```

Dataset:

[image]

Comment: You will want to set `return_sequences=False`. [Another thread on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376770/rnn-what-is-the-use-of-return-sequences-in-lstm-layer-in-keras-framework)

Comment: @finlaymorrison I set in 4th layer. Instead, if I set dense layer with 1 unit, does it mean the output made use all the features?