# Incompatible shapes Mean Squared Error Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to train a RNN with Keras, the shape for the X is `(4413, 71, 19)` while for y is `(4413,2)`

Code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None,19)))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None,19)))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None,19)))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

When I fit the model I got this error, seems that the loss function can't fit with this kind of data

```
Incompatible shapes: [64,2] vs. [64,71,2]
     [[{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_157671]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the parameter `return_sequences` of the last `LSTM` layer to `False`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None,19)))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

I have also changed the activation function in the output layer to `linear`, since a `softmax` layer does not make much sense in your case. Also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51376770/rnn-what-is-the-use-of-return-sequences-in-lstm-layer-in-keras-framework).